# Filter d3 js objects based on form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am using d3js to display a network of nodes and edges. Within the visualization, I am including an option [HTML Form input] to search nodes. Input can be more than one node.

I am having a hard time filtering multiple nodes using the filter function. I searched quite a bit but didn't find a similar issue. Here is the relevant code:

```
$("#submit-search").submit(function(event) {
     // values separated by commas
    var ip = $("#search-nodes").val().split(',');
    // converts to integers
    for(var i=0; i<ip.length; i++) {ip[i] = parseInt(ip[i], 10);}
    visualization.selectAll('circle')
    .filter(function(d){
         return ip.indexOf(d.name) != -1 ? d.name : false;
    })
    .style("stroke-width", 15)
    .style("stroke-opacity", 0.75)
    .style("fill", "black");
});
```

Since indexOf function returns only the first hit, only one node is highlighted. I tried to use jQuery's grep function without success.

Added an image of the visualization. Since I'm using django framework locally, it is not available publicly.

[image]

Edit: included jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZqzbN/ [erroneous]

Nodes have the attributes: degree centrality, group, name, betweenness centrality, degree
Edges have the attributes: source node, destination node, group

Comment: Hmm, could you put up a complete example somewhere please? Hard to tell what's going on with just a fragment.

Comment: I added the image of the visualization since I couldn't port the code to jsfiddle. Is that helpful?

Comment: That image is so low-res that I can't really make out what's in the boxes. It does look like your code should work however.

Comment: Can you post more info about the data and what values are returned by your form?  It looks like your array `ip` contains integers, but you are comparing them for a match with a `d.name` field, which I presume is a string.  The `indexOf` function [uses strict (===) equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), which means strings and integers won't get coerced to match.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, Apologize for the low quality image, included the jsfiddle (it's not working as expected)

Comment: @AmeliaBR, values returned by form are currently integers but can potentially strings (will worry about that later). Thank you for pointing it out. Fixed it now. It seems that is the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I have no familiarity with d3js but the easiest solution I can come up with is separate the filter functionality outside of visualization scope. I would recommend something like this. It's only pseudo code:

```
var new_array;

for each node in ip:
  insert node.name into new_array if node.name != -1
end

visualization.do_your_stuff_with(new_array);
```

Comment: The issue is in the comparison of strings and integers as Amelia pointed out.